# Extract Mongoid documents based on the DateTime of their last has_many relations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a bunch of `orders`, and some of them have `order_confirmations`.

1: I wish to extract a list of `orders` based on the `DateTime` of its last `order_confirmation`. This is my failed attempt (returns 0 records):

```
Order.where(:order_confirmations.exists => true).desc("order_confirmations.last.datetime")
```

2: I wish to extract a list of `orders` where the last `order_confirmation` is between 5 and 10 days old. This is my failed attempt (returns 0 results):

```
Order.lte("order_confirmations.last.datetime" => 5.days.ago).gte("order_confirmations.last.datetime" => 10.days.ago)
```

My relations:

```
class Order
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :order_confirmations
end

class OrderConfirmation
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :datetime, type: DateTime
  belongs_to :order
end
```

Comment: When you say "failed attempt", what do you mean? No results returned?

Comment: In `OrderConfirmation`, you declare field before even including `Mongoid::Document`. That would probably raise a `NoMethodError`. (I also wonder why you need these "inverse_of" options here.)

Comment: @GoshaArinich, I have updated my question. The failed attempts are returning 0 results. The missing include Mongoid::Document was a "typo".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With referenced relationships, you cannot directly query referenced documents.

That said, you would probably want to query order confirmations first, and then select the orders like this:

```
OrderConfirmation.between(datetime: 10.days.ago..5.days.ago)
  .distinct(:order_id).map { |id| Order.find(id) }
```

If you had confirmations embedded into the order, like this

```
class Order
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :order_confirmations
end

class OrderConfirmation
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :datetime, type: DateTime
  embedded_in :order
end
```

Then you could query order confirmation inside order query with `$elemMatch`:

```
Order.elem_match(order_confirmations:
  { :datetime.gte => 10.days.ago, :datetime.lte => 5.days.ago })
```

Regarding your first question, I don't think it's possible to do that with just MongoDB queries, so you could do something like

```
# if you go embedded rels
Order.all.map { |o| o.order_confirmations.desc(:datetime).first }
  .sort_by(&:datetime).map(&:order)

# if you stay on referenced rels
OrderConfirmation.desc(:datetime).group_by(&:order)
  .map { |k, v| v.first }.map(&:order)
```

Comment: Great, thanks. In regards to my first issue, if I used embedded relations, how should I then extract a list of `orders` where `order_confirmations` exists, and then sort the `orders` by the `datetime` of the `order_confirmations` (if an `order` has many `order_confirmations`, the oldest one should be used in the sorting)?

Comment: Thanks @Gosha Arinich. I have switched to an embedded relationship. I have two comments. Will break them into seperate comments:

Comment: 1) In order to handle cases where not all `orders` have `order_confirmations` you could do `Order.where(:order_confirmations.exists => true).map { |o| o.order_confirmations.desc(:datetime).first }.sort_by(&:datetime).map(&:order)`.

Comment: 2) Apparently, `Order.elem_match(order_confirmations:
  { :datetime.gte => 10.days.ago, :datetime.lte => 5.days.ago })` matches all orders where one of the criterias are met. So it returns all `orders` that have `order_confirmations`. Btw: Could you refactor this code so the last `order_confirmation` is be used?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the elemMatch function.

```
where('$elemMatch' => [{...}]
```

I do believe there is a bug in mongoid though related to elemMatch and comparing dates, not sure if its been fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you maybe elaborate a bit more. Not quite sure I get `elem_match`...

Comment: elemMatch says that everything in order for a record to be a match it must match each criteria in the elemMatch, otherwise it will pull stuff that matches just one of your criteria. You need to do this for embedded records, hashes, etc.